# Wordpress Autooptimizer plugin conflict with lazyload plugin

Tags: wordpress, performance

i have installed Auto optimizer plugin for increasing my Google page loading speed. It was working, it increased my speed. to increase speed more i installed Lazyload plugin as will. Now speed become doubled. Its worked as will.
   But i have a problem. What auto optimizer was doing is that it was replacing Image tag with a div whose background image was that image itself. Due to installation of lazyload that functionality disturebed.[image]

can this error be resolved keeping both plugins, as both plugin have their combine role in speed optimization.
[image]

if i deactivate Lazyload than auto-optimizer is replacing this.
[image]

Please help

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developers of the Autoptimize plugin to ask them about this already?

Comment: no,  i have not asked them.